# Android Studio decodingFile not working, how to proceed?

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

camera.java

```java
final File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null) ,"/CCA_" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()) + ".jpg");
                    ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imageReader) {
                            Image image;
                            image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                            ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                            buffer.get(bytes);
                            OutputStream outputStream = null;
                            try {
                                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                outputStream.write(bytes);
                                imgTaken =  file.getPath();
                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } finally {
                                if (outputStream != null) {
                                    try {
                                        outputStream.close();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };
```

using this function to save the image taken.

scenarioFire.java

```java
Bitmap bmpPhoto =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFilePath);

List<ImageDetection.Recognition> predictions = imageDetection.recognizeImage(bmpPhoto,0);
final List<String> lstPredictions = new ArrayList<>();

for(ImageDetection.Recognition recognition : predictions){
    lstPredictions.add(recognition.getName() + "- Confidence: " + recognition.getConfidence());
    Log.e("Prediction: " , recognition.getName() + "- Confidence: " + recognition.getConfidence());
    imageContains += recognition.getName() + "- Confidence: " + recognition.getConfidence() + "\n";
}
```

in this file i am trying to decode the jpeg into bitmap so it can be passed onto the tensorflow function to recognize the image, but the image cannot be decoded.

i have tried every solution on most forums and nothing seems to work.

keeps returning null. i have tried to see if it was the size affecting it or the location but those seem to be okay.
dont know how to proceed

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.thesisproject, PID: 24724
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2404, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.thesisproject/com.example.thesisproject.Scenarios.scenarioFire_details}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List classes.ImageDetection.recognizeImage(android.graphics.Bitmap, int)' on a null object reference

Comment: `imageDetection`. Have you initialised it?

Comment: yea but its not even going there, it crashes here Bitmap bmpPhoto =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFilePath);  it always returns null

Comment: How do you supply the path to the method? If you are unsure about getting the full path try something like `String fname=new File(getFilesDir(), "test.png").getAbsolutePath();`.

Comment: tried that still did not work, before posting i tried i think almost every solution people gave in stack over flow and other forums but nothing worked.

Comment: `Bitmap bmpPhoto =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFilePath);` So you say that bmpPhoto is null. Well add code to check for null and display a toast to inform the user and then stop return. Dont blindly continue to let your app crash.

Comment: We cannot see what you use for imageFilePath. Please tell full path.  And better.. put it in your code so we know what you do.

Comment: full path is = /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.thesisproject/files/image.jpg

Comment: OK. But does the bitmap become null? We try to help you and you do not react on some suggestions. Did you try/add the suggested code? What happens? Add the code in your post too.

Comment: what do you mean i do not react? i answer immediately. As i have said before i tried every suggestion. the result is the same bmpPhoto becomes null.